# VBA Sorting Table Based on Integer Variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have Loop I created that should count number of cells in Column A that are colored with ping background. If the cell is not pink then I delete the entire row. every time this loop excuted there are about to 400 rows and the loop is very slow. I want to change the loop I created to something else.

I want just to check the rows from the second to the last (i to LR_Double in the code) and then mark as "j" all the rows the is pink in column A. Afterwards, I want to sort the rows in a way that all "j" rows will be first and to delete the other rows.

Another problem that is can be a case that there would not be any cells with pink background at all. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
Public tmpFile As Workbook
Public LR_Double As Long
Public i As Long
Public j As Long

LR_Double = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
With tmpFile.Worksheets(2)
   ' i row number
   ' j duplicates number
        j = 0
    For i = LR_Double To 2 Step - 1
        If .Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
            j = j + 1
        Else
           .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: pink? rather than ping? ;-)

Comment: Are you refering to these public variables elsewhere in more code? I'm just wondering as to the actual scope for them. Also, bad practice to decrement i within a loop that is running in the opposite direction.

Comment: What's the value of LR_Double?  How's it calculated?

Comment: shouldnt you be putting  .Cells(i, "A") = "j" if the If condition is true , get rid of the Else part of the current code and then at the end simply do a descending sort on Range("A2:A" & LR_Double) - assuming nothing else in col A (otherwise do use the Else part of the code and have .Cells(i, "A") = vbNullString in it.

Comment: If you increment a counter within the If ..True part of the statment you will know how many rows had the "j" assigned i.e. are pink and so can offset from A2 by this to do your delete of rows (if count >0).

Comment: When you are deleting rows, it's better to process rows backwards:  "For i = LR_Double To 2 Step - 1"  Then you wouldn't need the "i = i - 1" loop craziness.

Comment: @QHarr I dont refer to the variables in other places in the code, I just have lots of subs so I name every variable as public

Comment: @GordonBell I name the last row dynamiclly. I edited the code

Comment: @QHarr I dont know how to insert your ideas within the code, can you be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like (with dummy value in for `LR_Double` and `tempFile`; and local variables rather than global). `i` and `counter` will be initialized as 0 but I like to explicitly state this:

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim tmpFile As Workbook
    Dim LR_Double As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    i = 0
    LR_Double = 6
    counter = 0

    Set tmpFile = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = tmpFile.Worksheets(2)

    With ws

        For i = 2 To LR_Double

            If .Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Value = "j"
                counter = counter + 1
            Else
                .Cells(i, "A").Value = vbNullString
            End If

        Next i

        Dim sortRange As Range

        Set sortRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & LR_Double)

        SortData sortRange

        .Range("A" & 2 + counter & ":A" & LR_Double).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SortData(ByVal sortRange As Range)

       sortRange.Sort key1:=sortRange.Cells(1, 1), _
      order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```